# How do you indicate line breaks in a poem when it is written without actual line breaks?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, poetry

In English, if you have a poem, like

> Roses are red,
>   Violets are blue,
>   Sugar is sweet,
>   And so are you.

and you need to write it on just one line (for reasons of space or whatever), you would write it like this:

> Roses are red, / violets are blue, / sugar is sweet, / and so are you.

That is, you use a single forward slash to separate the lines of the poem.

What is the equivalent of this in Japanese? I know that in some cases, you can just omit the line breaks altogether, e.g. writing

> 古池や
>   蛙飛び込む
>   水の音

as

> 古池や蛙飛び込む水の音

But supposing you did need to indicate the line breaks, how would you do so?

Answer (score 2):

Japanese doesn't traditionally use spaces, so a space will indicate a line break. For example,

八雲立つ　出雲八重垣　妻籠みに　八重垣作る　その八重垣を

Which, if choose to write it in rōmaji, is

Yakumo tatsu / Izumo yaegaki / Tsuma-gomi ni / Yaegaki tsukuru / Sono yaegaki wo

I will say, however, texts containing poems would almost always be written vertically, so the need to write a poem horizontally is rare.